# Can i add and/or replace audio sources in oboe without restarting the audio stream?

Tags: c++, audio, android-ndk, oboe

I need to extract audio assets on the fly and load them in to a timeline for playback.

I also need to render varying lengths of the asset files, but I have an idea I'm going to try out tomorrow that will sort that I think, if anyone has any tips that would be great though.

I have been playing with *oboe RhythmGame* code which is the closest, of the *oboe* samples, to what i'm trying to do. But it's not happy when I try and add or change audio sources on the fly.

**Is this something oboe can do or will I have to cycle the audio stream on and off for each new set of files?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're proposing can definitely be done without needing to restart the audio stream. The audio stream will just request PCM data on each callback. It's your app's job to supply that PCM data.

In the RhythmGame sample compressed audio files are decoded into memory using the `DataSource` object. The `Player` object then wraps this `DataSource` to control playback through the `set` methods.

If you need to play audio data from files in a timeline I would create a new Timeline class which copies the relevant sections of audio data from `DataSource`s and places them sequentially into a buffer. Then your audio stream can read directly from that buffer on each callback.

Comment: Hi Don, thanks for your answer. So I should read the timeline buffer directly into the outputBuffer of the DataCallBackResult of the audio stream, and would I then use the mixer in the timeline to combine multiple tracks from the DataSources on the fly??

Comment: You could definitely do it that way. To be clear you'd need to copy the timeline buffer into the `audioData` array which is a parameter to `onAudioReady` - `DataCallbackResult` is simply the return type of that method (it just tells the audio stream to either continue or stop)

Comment: Awesome, Thanks for your help Don

Comment: No problem, if my answer helped you please consider upvoting it. Thanks.